# How do I get the index of a newly added item in a list in C#?

Tags: c#, list, indexing

When I add an item (an instance of a class) to a list, I need to know the index of the new item. Is it possible with any function?

Example code:

```
MapTiles.Add(new Class1(num, x * 32 + cameraX, y * 32 + cameraY));
```

Comment: Does MapTiles inherit from List<T>? If not, please post the MapTiles class. Otherwise your index is MapTiles.Count-1 since Add appends to the end of the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MapTiles.Count` will give you the index of next item that will be added to the list

Something like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Adding " + MapTiles.Count + "th item to MapTiles List");
MapTiles.Add(new Class1(num, x * 32 + cameraX, y * 32 + cameraY));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Class1 newTile = new Class1(num, x*32 + cameraX, y*32 + cameraY);
MapTiles.Add(newTile);
int index = MapTiles.IndexOf(newTile);
```

Comment: Using .Count would be faster as the size of the list is maintained in state but using Index seems more correct/readable to me.

Comment: Don't use `IndexOf()` as it returns the *first* occurrence of the object. If you have the same object added multiple times, use `LastIndexOf()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're always using the `.Add(T);` method and not using `.Remove(T);`, then the index will be `Count - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Read `Count` immediately before adding.

```
int index = MapTiles.Count;
MapTiles.Add(new Class1(num, x * 32 + cameraX, y * 32 + cameraY));
```